# java - arraylist check if element exits here ignore the case

Tags: java

Hi i have the arraylist it stores the string values. I want to check the some string is exists in the list or not. Here i want ignore the case sensitive.

**code**

```
public static ArrayList< String > arrFoodItems = new ArrayList< String >();

if(arrFoodItems.contains("string"))

        {
            System.out.println("already available in the List.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not available");
        }
```

It's working fine. But in the following example it fails. How to do it without using loops.
Example: List contains: "Rice, Chicken,..."
Now you are check for "rice" is exits in the list. In this case we are getting "not exists".

**Don't using this**

```
for(int i=0; i < arrFoodItems.size(); i++)
{

   if(arrFoodItems.get(i)..equalsIgnoreCase(string))
   {
        System.out.println("already available in the List.");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could put all your strings in a `TreeSet` with a custom Comparator that ignores the case:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Chicken", "Duck");
Set<String> set=  new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
set.addAll(list);
System.out.println(set.contains("Chicken")); //true
System.out.println(set.contains("chicken")); //true
```

For more complex strategies / locale, you can also use a Collator:

```
final Collator ignoreCase = Collator.getInstance();
ignoreCase.setStrength(Collator.SECONDARY);

List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Chicken", "Duck");
Set<String> set=  new TreeSet<String>(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return ignoreCase.compare(o1, o2);
    }
});
set.addAll(list);
System.out.println(set.contains("Chicken"));
System.out.println(set.contains("chicken"));
```

Comment: There is such a comparator defined in String already; `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`

Comment: but what about if list contains multiple nulls.

Comment: @amicngh The implementation I propose is there to show an example - you would obviously add null checks in a final version

Answer (score 5):

Looping through the elements is what contains does for you so if you don't want to use a loop, its best not to use an ArrayList.

Without using a different collection your best option is to use

```
FOUND: {
    for(String item: arrFoodItems) {
       if (item.equalsIgnoreCase(string)) {
          System.out.println(string+" already available in the List.");
          break FOUND;
       }
    }
    System.out.println(string + " not available");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Collections.binarySearch static method which let you provide a comparator ( in this case String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Joe");
Collections.binarySearch(list, "joe", String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER); // return 0
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that ["The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the specified comparator"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator)) for which you could call [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))

Answer (score 2):

Why don't just write your `CustomArrayList` and then override `contains` method like below. Now you can use `CustomArrayList` in place of `ArrayList`.

**Example:**

```
public class CustomArrayList extends ArrayList<String> {
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        String str = (String)o;
        for (String s : this) {
            if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Test
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> myList=new CostumArrayList();
        myList.add("Amit");

        System.out.println(myList.contains("AMIT"));
        System.out.println(myList.contains("amit"));
    }
}
```