# Java Set<String> equality ignore case

Tags: java, set, ignore-case

I want to check if all elements of two sets of String are equal by ignoring the letter's cases.

```
Set<String> set1 ;
Set<String> set2 ;
.
.
.
if(set1.equals(set2)){ //all elements of set1 are equal to set2 
 //dosomething
}
else{
 //do something else
}
```

However, this equality check doesn't ignore the cases of the string. Is there some other way of doing that?

Comment: I think we need a little more info.  A `String` can only appear once in a `Set<String>`.  But is it possible, in your application, for two strings, `s1` and `s2`, to both be in a set if `s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2)` is `true`?  If so, then what's the criteria for two sets being equal if one set does contain two or more equivalent strings?  I think the solution is going to depend on nuances like that.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Alternatively you can use `TreeSet`.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Set<String> s1 = new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    s1.addAll(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a", "b", "c"}));

    Set<String> s2 = new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    s2.addAll(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"A", "B", "C"}));

    System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
}
```

Comment: Note that although this works, it is a very dangerous to assume that equality will be based on the Comparator and not on the equals() method. Implementation may change in the future.

Comment: @ShimiBandiel So long as the comparator is "consistent with equals" then by definition there is no danger. Correct? The Javadoc for `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` don't indicate one way or another.

Comment: @Gili I meant the the example provided assumes that the TreeSet equals uses the provided Comparator.

Comment: @ShimiBandiel I see. In that case your assertion is wrong. The fact that TreeSet uses Comparator for equals is not an implementation detail. It is explicitly guaranteed by the Javadoc and the latter is TreeSet's API contract / specification. Neither Sun nor Oracle ever change the specifications of public APIs.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, Java does not let you supply an external "equality comparer": when you use strings, `HashSet` uses only built-in `hashCode` and `equals`.

You can work around this problem by populating an auxiliary `HashSet<String>` with strings converted to a specific (i.e. upper or lower) case, and then checking the equality on it, like this:

```
boolean eq = set1.size() == set2.size();
if (eq) {
    Set<String> aux = new HashSet<String>();
    for (String s : set1) {
        aux.add(s.toUpperCase());
    }
    for (String s : set2) {
        if (!aux.contains(s.toUpperCase())) {
            eq = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (eq) {
    // The sets are equal ignoring the case
}
```

Comment: Based on something I started looking into some time ago (but didn't quite finish): I believe that solutions that involve normalizing the strings (such as `toUpperCase`) work if the letters in the `String`s are all in the A-Z or a-z range, or all in the Latin-1 set (0-255).  But if the letters may include all letters in the Unicode set, there are some letters that, I believe, screw up attempts at a simple normalization function.

Answer (score 4):

Not that I know of.

The best solution I can see, albeit over-engineered, would be to create your custom holder class holding a `String` instance field (`String` is `final` and cannot be inherited).

You can then override `equals` / `hashCode` wherein for two `String` properties `equalsIgnoreCase` across two instances, `equals` would return `true`and `hashCode`s would be equal.

This implies:

- `hashCode` returns a hash code based on a lower (or upper) cased
  property's hash code.
- `equals` is based on `equalsIgnoreCase`

  ```
  class MyString {
      String s;

      MyString(String s) {
          this.s = s;
      }
      @Override
      public int hashCode() {
          final int prime = 31;
          int result = 1;
          result = prime * result + ((s == null) ? 0 : s.toLowerCase().hashCode());
          return result;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object obj) {
          if (this == obj)
              return true;
          if (obj == null)
              return false;
          if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
              return false;
          MyString other = (MyString) obj;
          if (s == null) {
              if (other.s != null)
                  return false;
          }
          else if (!s.equalsIgnoreCase(other.s))
              return false;
          return true;
      }

  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
          Set<MyString> set0 = new HashSet<MyString>(
              Arrays.asList(new MyString[]
                  {
                      new MyString("FOO"), new MyString("BAR")
                  }
              )
          );
          Set<MyString> set1 = new HashSet<MyString>(
              Arrays.asList(new MyString[]
                  {
                      new MyString("foo"), new MyString("bar")
                  }
              )
          );
          System.out.println(set0.equals(set1));
   }
  ```

**Output**

```
true
```

... as said, over-engineered (but working).

Comment: many thanks, your solution indeed works. someone just posted this interesting page and then removed  [This Link].(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214576/java-arraylist-check-if-element-exits-here-ignore-the-case/12214608#12214608). This will do me too.

Comment: @nafas you're welcome. The linked solution actually looks much better than mine :)

Comment: The problem with this is that, if you already have a Set<String>, you will need to rebuild it.

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but this is the general idea:

```
public boolean setEqualsIgnoreCase(Set<String> a, Set<String>b)
{
    if (a.size() != b.size()) return false;
    Iterator<String> ai = a.iterator();
    Iterator<String> bi = b.iterator();
    while(ai.hasNext())
    {
         if (!ai.next().equalsIgnoreCase(bi.next())) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This would also compar ethe order of the sets, and the Set interface does not provide any ordering guarantees.

Comment: Also, it is not making use of the efficient contains method, which is very less compared to comparing each element!

Answer (score 0):

I would build something like this (in some form of Java pseudo code):

```
Set<String> set1;
Set<String> set2;

if (set1.size() != set2.size()) {
  return NOT_EQUAL;
} else {
  Set<String> set3 = new HashSet<String>();
  for (String s: set1) set3.add(s.toUpperCase());
  for (String s: set2) set3.add(s.toUpperCase());
  return set1.size() == set3.size() ? EQUAL : NOT_EQUAL;
}
```

Comment: As soon as you are able to add a string from set2 to set3 you know that set1 and set2 are different.

Answer (score -7):

You can use a loop and equalsIgnoreCase

```
testString.equalsIgnoreCase()
```

Comment: the question is about comparing `Set<String>`, while you're referring to a method of `String`. These are not interchangeable, but I guess you could turn it into a proper answer by adding a loop around.